# How can I bind a string to double in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding

I want to set a binding. The problem is that the target is of type string but the source is of type double.
In the following code VersionNumber is of type double. When I run this, the textblock is empty, without throwing any exceptions.
How can I set this binding?

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=VersionNumber}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

Comment: Is it possible the `VersionNumber` property you're binding to isn't a double, which might explain why you're not seeing the binding behavior you expect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a converter:

```
namespace Jahedsoft
{
    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(string))]
    public class StringConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value == null ? null : value.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:j="clr-namespace:Jahedsoft">

    <j:StringConverter x:Key="StringConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>

...

<Style TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MyControl}">
                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=VersionNumber, Converter={StaticResource StringConverter}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

Comment: You do not need a converter for this, if you are willing to accept the .ToString Format, or if you have SP1 and can use the StringFormat property of the Binding. The problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

There is a small difference in the examples.

Binding a double to the Text property works fine if you are using a Texblock directly in Window or another control, since it defaults back to the ToString() method, BUT this doesn't work if you try to use it in a ControlTemplate.

Then you need a Converter like it was suggested in the post.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a ValueConverter. Double to String targets work just fine. As a rule, Binding will call ToString() as a last resort.

Here's an example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="w1">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Version, ElementName=w1}" />
</Window>
using System;
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public double Version { get { return 2.221; } }
    }
}
```

The problem is probably that your Binding source isn't what you think it is. 
As a rule binding failures in WPF do not raise exceptions. They do log their failures however. See [How can I debug WPF bindings?](https://web.archive.org/web/20120120010534/http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=52)

Comment: Moheb, Try the simple example. Double to string is very common and is done all the time